# Codebird.js for Twitter API won't return more than one tweet in single call

Tags: javascript, twitter

Codebird.js is not working when I try to return a list of n number of tweets by adding to my params object.

It works when I include just the property `screen_name` to get a single tweet but when I add `count` in, as below, the response I get is still for only one tweet

```
params = {
    "screen_name": screenName,
    "count": "3"
};
```

I can't seem to find any codebird.js documentation besides the README.MD on the main github page.

Is my syntax correct? Am I approaching this the correct way by adding to `params`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Turns out I was using the wrong api endpoint and should have been using `statuses/user_timeline`.

Note: Check this part of the docs to see how to map this endpoint's string to the right format https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-js#mapping-api-methods-to-codebird-function-calls